# GCE shutdown script in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am wondering if it possible to specify a shutdown script in terraform when provisioning a GCE VM

Currently, I am using GCE to run GitHub Actions Runners, and I want to cleanly deregister the runner if the VM is shutdown.

This will be important if I decide to move to pre-emptive VMs or managed instance groups. For the latter, I'm planning on implementing a cloud function to scale down and scale up runner instances based on demand.

I have successfully provisioned my VMs in terraform with a startup script, as that is well documented, but I can not see a way to specify a shutdown script. Is that possible? Maybe using a meta tag in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely, you can specify shutdown script within you google_compute_instance like so:

```
  metadata = {
    shutdown-script = file("${path.module}/shudown_script.sh")
  }
```

Comment: That's the crucial thing I have been missing, thank you so much

Comment: Should this work if running terraform apply where a vm will need to be destroyed?  I've set this up, but I don't see any evidence of it running in the terraform output, nor in /var/log/messages as the machine is being powered off.